# Is there any cloud storage app for Android in which we can upload folders?

Tags: cloud-service, cloud-storage, cloud

Almost every cloud cloud storage app I have downloaded (including Google drive) there is no option to upload folder, there is only option to upload individual files. 
Also, in Google Drive there is a feature to upload folders but it is present only in desktop mode and I unable to upload folders on the mobile app/ site opened through mobile brower even using desktop mode